# Spotify Web JS wrapper-posting multiple tracks (not from playlist)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, spotify

I am attempting to use the Spotify Web API JS wrapper from the following repo:

https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js

My goal here is to pull  multiple tracks from Spotify and print them to a playlist on a webpage.The final version would ideally display up to 15 tracks at a time. Would this require an individual

for each? I'm pretty new to using API's so I will display the relevant JS and HTMl below for reference. Thank you for your help!

```
 var spotifyApi= new SpotifyWebApi();
    //access token (optional)
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken();

    Constr.prototype.getTracks = function(trackIds, options, callback) {
        var requestData = {
          url: _baseUri + '/tracks/',
          params: { ids: trackIds.join(',') }
        };
        return _checkParamsAndPerformRequest(requestData, options, callback);
      };
```

HTML

```
<div class="playlist">
    <p>Upload of tracks requires valid Spotify account</p>

<a href="https://www.spotify.com/us/signup/">Sign up here</a>

   <div class="search">
       <input type="search">
       <p>Enter Artist Here</p>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li type='none'id="tracks">
        </li>
    </ul>  

</div><!--playlist-->
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [an endpoint in the Spotify Web API for fetching multiple tracks at the same time](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-tracks/) that accepts an `ids` query parameter with comma separated track ids. That is the endpoint used in the `getTracks()` function of the wrapper you are using.

From your question, I don't really know if you want to add those tracks to a playlist or if you want to render tracks from an artist.

If you want to create a playlist with some tracks you will need the user to authorize your app. You have more information on the [Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/).

If you want to render tracks by an artist, you can also use some other endpoints like the one for [getting an artist's top tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artists-top-tracks/).

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the response. For the first phase of this project I simply want to add tracks to create a playlist. I've already authorized the application through my account. I've check out the getTracks endpoint as well. I believe my biggest problem would be how to pull all this together to make it work? I have most of the JS figured out, but I'm a little confused on getting it to display. I hope this added some clarity?

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at the [Code examples](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/). Those projects are open source and you can see how they interact with the Web API. If you have the data you want to display, it's a matter of creating some DOM elements and appending them to the document or use a template engine.

Comment: Thank you Jose, I'll take a look at these and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Justin, if you find JMPerez's answer to be correct, please set it as the correct answer so that others with similar issues finds it.